# Dynamically select options when page load base on textbox ng-model value in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

My select looks like this:

```
<select onchange="getVideo()" id="region">
     <option ng-repeat="items in region" ng-selected = "items.countryCode === selectedRegion" value="{{items.countryCode}}">{{items.countryCode}}</option>
</select>
```

This is my JSON:

```
$scope.region = [
    {
        countryItem : "TW(TW)",
        countryCode : "tw_zh_tw"
    },
    {
        countryItem : "US(EN)",
        countryCode : "us_en"
    },
    {
        countryItem : "US(ES)",
        countryCode : "us_es"
    },
    {
        countryItem : "JP(JA)",
        countryCode : "jp_ja"
    },
];
```

When the selectbox change it will call a function which is getVideo() function:

```
function getVideo() {
var language = $("#region option:selected").val();
location.href="/support/"+language+"/Videobackstage;
}
```

With this function, the pages always load when the select changes, so I need the value of the select to be retained even if the pages load.

To fix that I came up with a solution, I use the textbox ng-model as parameter for ng-select condition, the textbox is having a value and it works the way i want it, but for the select it is not working:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selectedRegion" id="selectedRegionx">
```

I am setting the value of the textbox by getting a specific value in the url:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var pageUrl = window.location.pathname;
var split = pageUrl.split("/");
var langUrl = split[2];
$("#selectedRegionx").val(langUrl);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I make global variable that can be accessed by angular controller:

```
var pageUrl = window.location.pathname;
var split = pageUrl.split("/");
var langUrl = split[2];
```

I just added a scope in my controller:

```
$scope.selectedRegion = langUrl;
```

It works fine now!